# MVC in php, model for categories?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model

I am building my first little app with PHP and trying to do MVC.

My website requires quite large arrays of cities and categories.

My question is a fairly simple one but as the arrays are data for the website all be it only php arrays, should the arrays be placed into their own models?

From what I understood models are used for business logic and accessing data, as the cities and categories are basically data does the justify them for having a model?

And if the answer is no why and what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Inb4 use a framework. <- Don't.

Comment: I don't want a framework, I don't learn using frameworks.

Comment: You should learn using a framework. 
Some willjust understand teh basics of design patterns.

Comment: @DaniloKobold, I don't want to throw a discussion over here, I'm just saying this: frameworks, especially PHP frameworks, are not perfect. Sometimes we just need of people like Griff to reinvent a better wheel, especially when most of the wheel out there are squared. Let him try. Then when it will need one he can always learn one.

Comment: I'm not saying he wont. I agree that frameworks might note have all the strengths but it will give him some practical knowledge to build a single example system with lets say symphony or zf. he will get the basics of mvc within the 2 hours he works on that. (before making it he must understand it or it will end up as square as)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model are responsible for retrieving, editing, deleting and generally manage data. Data usually comes from some static sources such as databases, XML files and such.

You should create model classes that interface with those data. That's what a model is supposed to do. Obviously you can hold data in private members the way you want, arrays, other classes etc.

You are probably wondering why is it a good idea? Well, data should be stored in classes because you can set visibility to class members. Data items are usually private so that you can decide what actions are allowed, leading to a general better design and security.

Also models usually don't contain any logic in them. It's the controller that deals with the logic. It's in the MV (Model / View) architecture that models implements some logic.

You can also take a look at how popular frameworks handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly what you need is to study a little more theory before jump into  building a MVC form scratch. The MVC is not connected to the business model in any way. It's software architecture. Yes, controllers might do the role of business layer but it's not the way of explaning it.

I'd strongly suggest you to do :

Use a framework for a while, Like Symphony2 or ZF. They will force you into mvc by default and that will improve your practical knowledge on it.

Read this book/bible [Design Patterns](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DesignPatternsBook)